# Why am I getting garbage values when I print the value?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, pimpl-idiom

I'm trying to learn about the PIMPL idiom, and c++ in general.

I have a class with a PIMPL style interface, that sets an int value to 7. But, I'm getting a garbage value when I print it, and I don't understand why.

**Code**

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
struct Foo::Bar
{
    int value;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    Bar tempBar;
    myBar = &tempBar;
    myBar->value = 7;
}
void Foo::printValue()
{
    std::cout << "Value = " << myBar->value << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    Foo myFoo;
    myFoo.printValue();
    return 0;
}
```

**Test.h**

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        struct Bar;
        Bar* myBar;
    public:
        Foo();
        void printValue();
        //~Foo();
};
```

**Output**

Value = 2147120498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mybar` is a pointer to a local variable inside the `Foo` constructor.  When the constructor exits, the variable is gone, but `myBar` is still pointing at the old memory.

Since you want to implement PIMPL, there is really only 1 choice.  You need to dynamically allocate `myBar` using `new`, and free it with `delete` in the `Foo` destructor.  You will also have to add a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator to `Foo` as well, to avoid leaking memory:

Test.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    myBar = new Bar;
    myBar->value = 7;
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo &src)
{
    myBar = new Bar;
    *myBar = *(src.myBar);
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete myBar;
}

Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo &rhs)
{
    *myBar = *(rhs.myBar);
    return *this;
}
```

Test.h

```
class Foo
{
private:
    struct Bar;
    Bar* myBar;
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo &src);
    ~Foo();

    void printValue();

    Foo& operator=(const Foo &rhs);
};
```

If you were not implementing PIMPL, then there would be another option.  Make `myBar` be a non-pointer member of the `Foo` class instead:

Test.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    myBar.value = 7;
}

void Foo::printValue()
{
    std::cout << "Value = " << myBar.value << std::endl;
}
```

Test.h

```
class Foo
{
private:
    struct Bar
    {
        int value;
    };

    Bar myBar;

public:
    Foo();
    void printValue();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using modern C++ you can do the pimpl this way:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
    struct Bar;
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> myBar;
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void printValue();
};
```

The `unique_ptr` is one of the few standard library containers that works with incomplete types. An advantage of this approach is that if you make a mistake such as commenting out the destructor, or trying to copy `Foo` then the compiler catches it for you.

The bodies in the .cpp file could be:

```
Foo::Foo(): myBar( new Bar ) { myBar->value = 7; }
Foo::~Foo() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tempBar` is being popped off the stack at the end of the constructor since it is a local variable, so you are hitting undefined behavior.

Perhaps you want to use `new` and `delete` in the destructor.

Comment: Or just change `Bar *myBar` to `Bar myBar` in the `Foo` class, and then use `myBar.value` instead of `myBar->value`.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. I was actually attempting to have the object on the stack. Is there a way I could structure it without needing the heap?

Comment: There is only the stack and the heap, there is nothing else. But you can make `Bar myBar` be a member of the `Foo` class without having to use `new` to allocate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the address of a temporary.  Instead, you need to *allocate* it:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    myBar = new Bar;
    myBar->value = 7;
}
```

And then you must follow the Rule of Three, providing a destructor and copy constructor.

Comment: Or just change `Bar *myBar` to `Bar myBar` in the `Foo` class, and then use `myBar.value` instead of `myBar->value`.

Comment: But then it's not _pimpl_ -- the whole point of that idiom is to hide the details of the implementation.

Comment: Can you explain how it's not PIMPL if were to make that change?

Comment: Because you must provide a definition for `Bar` visible at the point at which `myBar` is declared.  _i.e._ define `struct Bar` in your header file.  That's completely contrary to what _pimpl_ is about.  Hence why I jumped straight to the conclusion that you require dynamic allocation.

Comment: @justthom8 the first P in PIMPL stands for "pointer". If you use `Bar myBar` then you must put the full definition of `Bar` in the header file, and you are no longer doing PIMPL.

Comment: You are right, I missed the part of the question about PIMPL being used.